# Closing a workbook with RED X with Save prompt disabled and default selected "Don't Save"

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, the workbook I am working on is supposed to prevent a USERLIST from closing it without allowing it to first update another workbook and then saving.  I am trying to avoid adding a button that does this and just have it happen when the user clicks the RED X to close the window. However, there will be some instances when other nonusers access it and will not be able to update it.  I would like to give them the option to exit without updating and saving, but I am not sure how to disable the "Do you want to save" dialogue box with the default set to "Don't Save".  If I use the code

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

it restarts the entire process and loops it.  Is there a way to avoid that?  Please forgive the basic coding, as you might have gathered from my previous questions, I am learning all of this as I go.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

**Response = MsgBox(prompt:="Are you sure you are ready to close for the day?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
If Response = vbYes Then**
    SWEEPER = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    USER = Environ("username")

        For i = 1 To SWEEPER
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Activate
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Cells(1, i).Select

            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Cells(1, i).Value = USER Then
                Set DATES = Workbooks.Open _
                    ("test.xlsx")
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATES").Activate
                Call Date_Updates

            Exit Sub

            End If

        Next i
    **Else
    'Cancel = True
    'MsgBox "Master Not Updated."
    Response = MsgBox(prompt:="Are you trying to close without saving and updating?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
        If Response = vbYes Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Exit Sub
        Else
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Master Not Updated."
        End If
    Exit Sub**
End If
MsgBox "You are not authorized to edit this document."

End Sub

Sub Date_Updates()

USER = Environ("username")

SWEEPER = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To SWEEPER
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATES").Cells(1, i).Select
STATE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Cells(1, i).Value = USER Then
    For l = 2 To STATE
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATES").Cells(l, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
        STName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SET").Cells(l, ActiveCell.Column).Value



        CHECKED = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(STName).Range("R4")
        RESULT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(STName).Range("S4")

            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(STName).Range("R4") And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(STName).Range("S4") > "" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATES").Range("F2:I27").Find(What:=STName, After:=Range("I27"), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
                ActiveCell.Next.Activate
                ActiveCell = CHECKED
                ActiveCell.Next.Activate
                ActiveCell = RESULT
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATES").Range("A2:C21").Find(What:=STName, After:=Range("C21"), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate
            End If

    Next l
    MsgBox "Update Complete"
    DATES.Save
    DATES.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Exit Sub
End If


Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Which one of these MsgBox prompts is giving you trouble?  Or are both of them?

Comment: Once again, I believe I have answered my own question: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213428
Example 1: Close the workbook without saving changes

To force a workbook to close without saving any changes, type the following code in a Visual Basic module of that workbook:
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    
My Code:    
    ElseIf response = vbCancel Then
        response = MsgBox(prompt:="Master not updated. Are you trying to close without saving and updating?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
            If response = vbYes Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
            Exit Sub

Comment: +1 , but please for the sake of everyone else, don't try to put code in the comments. It doesn't fit, nor does it render properly (indentation, etc.).  If you've answered your question, add it as an *answer* :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Hehe, thanks so much for that.  I will post this with the proper formatting to answers when it allows me (still have to wait a few hours).  I just did it in comments so that I would have it there to post in the answers when the time came.  I am learning that this site is good at saving drafts of comments/answer, though.  Thanks so much for the feedback!  This site has been amazing for me so far!

Comment: I have learned a *ton* from just browsing this site, and finding new ways to solve problems that I already thought I knew how to do. It's a great resource once you start using it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, I believe I have answered my own question: How to suppress "Save Changes" prompt when you close a workbook in Excel

Example 1: Close the workbook without saving changes

To force a workbook to close without saving any changes, type the following code in a Visual Basic module of that workbook:

```
Sub Auto_Close()
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

My Code:

```
ElseIf response = vbCancel Then
    response = MsgBox(prompt:="Master not updated. Are you trying to close without saving and updating?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
        If response = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        Exit Sub
```